# opencv findTransformEcc inputMask argument

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have 2 images that I want to find the transformation that maps a subregion of the first image to a subregion of the second  image.
I tried using the opencv findTransformECC function. In their [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga7ded46f9a55c0364c92ccd2019d43e3a) they specify
that you can use the optional inputMask argument to indicate valid values of inputImage. But they dont specify what values should the inputMask take to ignore part of the input image.

Comment: if you want eyes on your posts, don't use niche tags (version-specific tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some testing I figured out that you just need to set the inputMask to zero in the input pixel positions that you want to ignore